# Manually install php , apache 2.2, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am stuck with this problem for 4 days and i cant solve it.
I have a zend 1 project. Php version 5.4.37 , apache 2.2.4.
First install Apache with msi installer. Apache configuration:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/Apache2.2/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
PHPIniDir "c:/Apache2.2/PHP"
```

Enable virtual hosts

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Enable rewrite_module

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Also the project needs apc ext for php so i included it too. Also in httpd.conf i pointed the php ext folder.

Vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@rma.com        
DocumentRoot "C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\rma\public"
ServerName rma.com
ErrorLog "logs/rma-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/rma-access.log" common
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\rma\public>
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And when i try to open rma.com i get "The page isn't redirecting properly" . 
What i amd doing wrong ? Thanks in advance !

UPDATE

In .htaccess i have this

```
# Option 1:
# Rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
#Rma Version Stamp for CSS and JS
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(.*).lvs([0-9]{5,10}).(css|js)$ /$1/$2.$4 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/1.0/soap.*$ /api/1.0/soap.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/1.0/json.*$ /api/1.0/json.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^deamon.*$ /deamon/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
    # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
      Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The project used to work before i uninstalled xampp. Now I want to learn how to configure my env manually.

Comment: Its likely your rewrite rules which I assume you have defined in an `.htaccess` that you have not shown. Please update the question with your rewrite rules. The very fact that you got that error message means Apache is working properly.

Comment: How is this a question about _installation_ of the components mentioned in your question title? (_At most_ it seems to be about _configuration_.)

Comment: It could be your app that causes what looks like an infinite redirection loop. Please include your rewrite rules and the URL you're hitting to get this error

Comment: Updated main post with htaccess